# Writing basic test case with JEST for infinity condition

Tags: javascript, function, testing, math, jestjs

Here I have added the **test file** and implementation ,I am trying to write a test case to check whether the **divisor is zero** and if it is zero send a message "infinity"

```
//code in test file  
    describe("valid divisions", () => {
        
          test("3 / 0 = infinity", () => {
          expect(divide(x,y)).toHaveReturnedWith('infinity');
        });
    });
    
    //code in js file
     
    const divide = (x, y) => {
        if (y===0){
         return('infinity');
        }
         else {
          return x / y;
         } 
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide is a function that takes two variables (named x and y), In your test, you are calling divide with values (x,y). These variables are not initialised anywhere, and you should instead be passing values to the function, i.e. `divide(3,0)`.

So your line would be

`expect(divide(3,0)).toHaveReturnedWith('infinity');`